# Windows App - LocalSettings - Completely Remove an Entry

Tags: javascript, win-universal-app

It is a simple question, but I cannot find the answer.

At the moment I have a value in the localsettings of 'myitem', it is the number 5. I want to completely remove it as if it had never been set before. How do i do that?

```
var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localSettings;
var val = localSettings.values["myitem"]; // This is the number 5
```

I want to know how to write `Obliterate` below which does the following:

```
var val = localSettings.values["myitem"]; // This is the number 5
Obliterate(localSettings.values["myitem"]);
var val = localSettings.values["myitem"]; // undefined, never heard of it
```

Comment: localSettings.values["myitem"]=undefined;

Comment: You are right - it works. There appears to be no more trace of it.